# Samba share randomly unable to move files/folders

Tags: permission, smb

I'm having strange permissions issues with my OSX 10.8.4 server. I stopped using the Apple v2.2.1 server app due to numerous issues & now have samba 3.6.15 installed via Macports, which mostly works ok except...
Every now & then OSX asks for a password when trying to move specific files or folders from one place to another (within the same volume) Entering the users own password doesn't work, he is already logged on to the server as himself & is able to move other folders, save files & otherwise work ok.
When I do a 'get info' to look at the permissions for that file, it has 'staff - read/write' even though staff is not set as owner group for that folder & none of the users have staff as their primary group id.
If I expand 'details' it is 'com.apple.desktopservices' that is asking for the password
Guessing 'staff' has something to do with it although any suggestions appreciated!
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research I've come up with a workable solution - at least I'm not changing it for the time being.
Check 'ignore ownership' is unticked on the external volume where the share resides.

Change the users primary group id from 'staff' to custom group id

```
sudo dscl . -change /Users/lmessi PrimaryGroupID 20 567
```

Remove all ACLs from External drive 'Disk1'

```
chmod -RN /Volumes/Disk1
```

[if you get any errors, try recursive unlock files beforehand]

```
sudo chflags -R nouchg /Volumes/Disk1
```

change group ownership recursively for the group 'design'

```
sudo chgrp -R design /Volumes/Disk1
```

You can check ownership with ls -gl

```
ls -gl /Volumes/Disk1
```

Then my smb.conf file looks something like this

```
[global]
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
    unix extensions = no

        guest ok = No
        read only = No
        force group = design

    create mask = 664
        force create mode = 664
        security mask = 664
        force security mode = 664
        directory mask = 2775
        force directory mode = 2775
        directory security mask = 2775
        force directory security mode = 2775

[Share1]
        comment = Share1
    path = /Volumes/Disk1/Share1
        valid users = mickey, donald
        admin users = mickey, donald
```